# unsigned int data types in c

Tags: c, types, implicit-conversion

Please help me in differentiating these codes in C:

Code 1:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t fb(int a)
{
    return -3;
}

int main()
{
    int a = fb(-3);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned int fb(int a)
{
    return -3;
}

int main()
{
    int a = fb(-3);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the the first code returns 253 as expected but the second code returns -3 which is unexpected as return type is unsigned. Please help me how this is possible?

I have used mingw gcc compiler.

Comment: Shall the answer assume "mingw gcc" is the only platform there is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first program,

1. When the function returns, `int` -3 (FFFFFFFD) is cast to `uint8_t` is 253 (FD). The higher order bytes are dropped so it fits.
2. When the assignment is performed, `uint8_t` 253 (FD) is cast to `int` by sign extension to 253 (000000FD).

In the second program,

1. When the function returns, `int` -3 (FFFFFFFD) cast to `unsigned int` 4294967293 (FFFFFFFD). No bytes needed to be dropped.
2. When the assignment is performed, `unsigned int` 4294967293 (FFFFFFFD) cast to `int` is -3 (FFFFFFFD).

Notes:

- Assumes 32-bit ints, but it's a similar story with 64-bit ints.
- This is an explanation of what happens for you; it isn't necessarily what the C spec calls to happen.

Comment: I am unable to get your point. Can you please elaborate it with more examples. It would be really grateful for all?

Comment: No mention of the rules, exceptions, other platforms, explanation, anything?

Comment: The conversion rules are different, though making the right assumptions including defining out-of-range conversion to signed appropriately, this might happen. Still no mention of the rules nor all your assumptions (OP never said he only wants x86 win-32bit and/or win-64bit).

Answer (score 2):

The conversion from signed to unsigned will follow the rules laid out in section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers* of the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) which says:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.<sup>49)</sup>

So this means that `-3` will be converted to by adding `UMAX +1` to the value. In the case of `uint8_t` this is a relatively small value `253` which fits into a *singed int* and therefore is converted to *signed int* without issue.

In your second case with the return value of *unsigned int*, we will end up with a rather large value upon conversion, actually `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max() + 1 - 3`. Which will not fit into an *signed int* this is overflow and is thus undefined behavior as per section `6.5` paragraph *5* which says:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

Comment: Waiting for more replies. :)

Answer (score 0):

The rule for conversion from integral type to an unsigned integral type is simple:
Add/Subtact (Maximum value of target type + 1) as often as needed to fit.

The rule for conversion from integral type to signd integral type is simpler still:
Preserve the value, if out-of-range the conversion is undefined.
Most modern implementations (all on windows platform) define it to add/subtract same constant as for corresponding `unsigned` type until it fits though.

Using those rules, the conversion on return from `fb()` in the first example is value-preserving and ok:
-3 -> 256-3 = 253 -> 253

The return in the second example is out-of-range and thus undefined behavior, though normally:
-3 -> 2<sup>CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)</sup>-3 -> -3

Bonus facts:

- Passing a variadic function a signed/unsigned type where the corresponding other one was expected is allowed, though the raw value cannot be converted and will just be assumed to be of the indicated type.
- `CHAR_BIT` is a preprocessor constant giving the number of bits in a byte.
- `sizeof` is an operator giving the number of bytes in a type / variable.

Comment: Unable to get 2**(CHAR_BIT*sizeof(int)) statement? Help please I'm beginner?

Comment: added the definition of those constants you asked for.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) May God bless You.

and If you could explain more, it would be so much helpful for me and others too.

Answer (score 0):

unsigned int should be printed as `%u` instead of `%d`

Comment: There is no `unsigned` variable to print though.

Comment: it is stated that "return type is unsigned" in the question, which it is in the code but when you print `%d` it doesn't matter what the actual type is it will print a signed int so to print an unsigned value you need `%u`

Comment: return type is unsigned but then assigned to a signed variable.

Comment: @Deduplicator, your answer was very nice and correct. However when you wish to print an int it doesn't matter if the variable is declared int or unsigned int. The system will just allocate the same 32 bits (or 64 depending on the system) and then when you request to print it will look at `%d` or `%u` and display those 32 bits in that way.
My answer will fix the so called "bug" which is in the display and not the value of the variable itself.

Comment: Re "it is stated that "return type is unsigned" in the question", but he's not printing the returned value. Re "However when you wish to print an int it doesn't matter if the variable is declared int or unsigned int", That's awful advice. If he wants to print it as an unsigned int, he shouldn't be assigning it to an int in the first place.

Comment: This "answer" is a comment that doesn't even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: This answer is the solution to the issue that @user3798282 experienced